# How do I download images to the folder I specify with Python urllib request?

Tags: python, image, save, urllib

For example, I want to download the pictures to the folder named pictures. How can I do this with urllib request

```
import os
import urllib.request
try:
    klasor_yarat = os.mkdir("resimler")
except:
    pass
say = 1
for i in resim_listesi:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(i,str(klasor_yarat)+"\"resim" +str(say)+ ".jpg")
    say+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be several problems here:

- `"\"resim"` is not the correct way to put a `'/'` in the string. You have to use `"/"` or `"\\"`.
- `str(klasor_yarat)` returns `"None"`.
- You are adding a `".jpg"` to the image retrieved. What if the image is a different extension?
- Make sure `resim_listesi` is an iterable. I can't know that because it's not defined in the code given.
- Lastly, try using English names for variables as that will improve the readability of your code for others.

Anyway, this should probably work.

```
import os
import urllib.request
try:
    klasor_yarat = os.mkdir("resimler")
except:
    pass
say = 1
for i in resim_listesi:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(i,"resimler/resim" +str(say)+ ".jpg")
    say+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) doesn't return anything, so `klasor_yarat` doesn't have any value in your code. Instead, create the path like this:

```
import os
import urllib.request

resimler = "resimler"

try:
    os.mkdir(resimler)
except:
    pass

say = 1
for i in resim_listesi:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, os.path.join(resimler, "resim" + str(say) + ".jpg"))
    say+=1
```

Use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create paths in a platform-independent way, instead of trying to add slashes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable through specifying the directory inside of your file name/path for the image.

For example:

```
import os
import urllib

try:
  os.mkdir("directory")
except:
  pass
  
url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, "directory/google.png")
```

Comment: OP's current code is already doing that.